# mySQL query ignoring NOT IN function

Tags: mysql

This query is processing and running but it is completely ignoring the NOT IN section

```
SELECT * FROM `offers` as `o` WHERE `o`.country_iso = '$country_iso' AND `o`.`id` 
not in (select distinct(offer_id) from aff_disabled_offers 
where offer_id = 'o.id' and user_id = '1') ORDER by rand() LIMIT 7
```

Comment: 'o.id' in the nested query is probably wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your "not in" query returns nothing.

Shouldn't the

```
where offer_id='o.id'
```

Be

```
where offer_id=o.id
```

?

Answer (score 0):

guido has the answer...  it looks like you meant to create a correlated subquery.  `'o.id'` is being seen as a literal.

SOME CAUTIONS:

You usually want some sort of guarantee that the subquery in the `NOT IN` predicate does NOT return a NULL value. If you don't have that guarantee enforced from the database, adding a `WHERE/HAVING return_expr IS NOT NULL` in the subquery is sufficient to give you that guarantee.

That correlated subquery is going to eat your lunch, performance wise, on large sets. As will that ORDER BY rand().

Generally, an anti-join pattern turns out to be much more efficient on large sets:

```
SELECT o.*
  FROM offers o
  LEFT
  JOIN aff_disabled_offers d
    ON d.user_id = '1'
   AND d.offer_id = o.id
 WHERE d.offer_id IS NULL
   AND o.country_iso = '$country_iso'
 ORDER BY rand()
 LIMIT 7
```